Ensure the correctness of timestamps, so that timestamps do not depend on the phone's time
I am planning to develop an IM type app. How can I ensure that the timestamp I set is correct when storing the message I want to send in the local database? (Even if I adjusted the time on my phone to two days ago)
How should I design this module to ensure the correctness of timestamps

if you don't trust the system clock, you can get time from a time server,
eg NIST Internet Time Servers.
AFAIK, the system clock (Foundation) does synchronize with a time server,
so this let timeStamp = Date() should give you accurate time.
You could also use the monotonic clock using for exmple,
let timeStamp = DispatchTime.now()

@workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks.When I changed the system time to two days ago, Date() returned timestamp was also from two days ago.
I can request the server to synchronize the timestamp. If it is a weak network, how can I handle the time loss in the link

have you tried let timeStamp = DispatchTime.now(), AFAIK this does not rely on the system clock.

@workingdogsupportUkraine How would convert from DispatchTime.now() to clock time? The docs say that is Mach absolute time, which is the number of (some unit, usually nanoseconds) of uptime since booting. You still need some way to tie that back to clock time.

yes I see the issues. Seems DispatchTime.now() is used many for measuring time differences rather than Date time as requested.
